# Grouping results from 2 tables

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables, one with a list of location ID's and identifiers, like this

```
PKID   LOCATIONID
232      656
2424     657
878      663
```

the other table has locationIDs, and a range of Mile Markers those locations ID's reference.

```
LocID   Roadway   StartMM     EndMM
656      I-40      373.5      376.4
657      I-40      373.5      376.4
658      I-40      373.5      376.4
660      I-40      377.5      381.4
661      I-40      377.5      381.4
662      I-40      377.5      381.4
66       I-40      377.5      381.4
```

Notice multiple LocIDs for the same StartMM and EndMM range

I need a count of how many times each locID in the first table occurs in the second table
For instance, in the example in the sample above, for the range 373.5 to 376.4 there are 2 entries in the first table that match, so the count would be 2. For the range 377.5 to 381.4 one locID in the first table matches the range.

My output needs to be something like

```
Roadway StartMM   EndMM   Count  
I-40     373.5    376.4     2
I-40     377.5    381.4     1
```

I hope this is clear... any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the match for 377.5 to 381.4??

Comment: nothing -- they dont all have to have a match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that LocID is unique in your second table you could do something as simple as this:

```
SELECT Roadway,StartMM, EndMM, count(*)
FROM Table2
GROUP by Roadway, StartMM, EndMM
```

Comment: Thanks -- didnt think it would be that simple but it is!!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Roadway,StartMM, EndMM, count(t1.locationid)
FROM Table2 t2
left join table1 t1
on t1.locationid = t2.locid
GROUP by Roadway, StartMM, EndMM
```

The count is 0 for marker ranges which don't have matching Location Ids in the first table. If you only need to show mile marker ranges that exist in the first table, change the left join to a inner join.